# JMS serializer multi-demension array to single array

Tags: json, symfony, doctrine, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

Following query is run by doctrine

```
SELECT o,  (SELECT count(f.id) FROM AppBundle:Feedback f WHERE f.order = o.id) isFeedbackAdded
FROM  AppBundle:Order o
WHERE o.provider = :provider
```

Result generated by JMS

```
"_embedded": {
    "items": [
        {
            "0": {
                "id": 5,
                ...
            },
            "isFeedbackAdded": "0"
        },
```

desired result we want is following

```
"_embedded": {
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            ...
            "isFeedbackAdded": "0"

        },
```

if I remove the subquery, then we do get the desired result, but after adding the subquery, then it split into further dimension array.

Can we include `isFeedbackAdded` in order entity property as a virtual field, rather than keeping it outside, so we get the desired result.

Comment: Add serializing code-part inside controller, the repository method that executes the query and an extraction of the relevant entity properties/methods to the question please.

Comment: too many fields, not a good solution